# Laravel Cashier: Cancelling a subscription gives error "Call to a member function asStripeCustomer() on null"

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Laravel Cashier for two types of subscriptions - for companies and individual users. I added the Billable trait to the Company model and I created a PersonalBillable trait for the User model. I also have a PersonalSubscription class where I specify that the User subscriptions should use 'personal_subscriptions' table. Company subscriptions use the default 'subscriptions' table that comes with Cashier migrations. Everything works perfectly fine except when I try to cancel a User subscription. The following code 
`auth()->user()->subscription('user')->cancel();` gives an error "Call to a member function asStripeCustomer() on null". 
Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

After going through the process of cancelling a subscription thoroughly I found what the problem was. In Subscription class the `owner()` function looks for the Billable model in `cashier.php` config file where the model was set to Company. What I did is just override this function in my PersonalSubscription custom class and specify the model to be User.

Answer (score 1):

**For V1.0 Spark**

For anyone out there encountering this issue using Laravel Spark and also using a Billable model different than User, You'll need to add to your .env file a Cashier config as well. This comes up when you are changing plans or updating credit card numbers for some reason. Don't know if it is a bug in Spark or not, but this seems to fix it.

```
CASHIER_MODEL=App\Models\Clients
```

**For V2.x Spark**

When upgrading to the latest version, the .env configuration is no longer necessary. However, you'll need to make sure to put some additional code in your App's main Service Provider. Currently, this is not well documented except in the upgrade guide:
https://spark.laravel.com/docs/2.x/spark-stripe/upgrade.html

```
use App\Models\Clients;

...

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Cashier::useCustomerModel(Clients::class);

}
```